# How to convert a very large 40gb ffdf to a disk.frame?

Tags: r, ff, disk.frame

Had it been smaller it would not have been difficult to use the as.data.table.ffdf function. But as it is, the file is much larger than my ram.

Is there any way I can convert it or do I need to write it to disk and then reload it?

Comment: I suspect using add_chunk would work. Will look at it in the morning